# Premature EOF exception in Java using BufferedReader

Tags: java, url, bufferedreader, eof, ioexception

I am trying to turn a url (its just text) into a string and I am reading the url with a BufferedReader. However, I keep getting a Premature EOF exception. Here is what I have so far.

```
 try {
        URL sUrl = new URL(url);
        String result = "";
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sUrl.openStream()));
            String av;
            while ((av = br.readLine()) != null) {
                result += av;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(result.length());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Also, I tried implementing this solution, which I saw on another stackoverflow thread.

```
try {
        URL oracle = new URL(url);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

        StringBuffer input = new StringBuffer();
        int BUFFER_SIZE = 2000000;
        char[] buffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
        int charsRead = 0;
        while ((charsRead = in.read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) != -1) {
            input.append(buffer, 0, charsRead);
        }
        in.close();
        System.out.println(input.toString().length());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Both of these approached lead to the same error occuring at the .read / .readLine part of my code.

Here is the stacktrace.

```
java.io.IOException: Premature EOF
at java.base/sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.fastRead(ChunkedInputStream.java:257)
at java.base/sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:689)
at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3501)
at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
at java.base/java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:185)
at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:326)
at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:392)
at com.github.doomsdayrs.jikan4java.ExampleClass.main(ExampleClass.java:99)
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: java.io.IOException: Premature EOF

Comment: Why are you not using [NIO.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html), for example, capturing a web page and saving it to a file using [Files.copy(in, path)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.io.InputStream,java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.CopyOption...))?

Comment: I thought that it might create a lot of clutter if I made a new file for every unique new url. I but I did try converting the url into a file and then reading from the file and that worked. Is there a good way to delete files shortly after they are generated in an efficient manner, I haven't looked into it and am new to stuff like this.

Comment: Can you confirm if the exception occurs at the end of the content you want to read, or it just randomly pops up somwhere in the middle? If it always occurs at the end of content it can mean that either there is a Java bug there, or that concent is malformed. You could try wrapping the read or readLine call in try/catch block, and catch IOException as signal that it is end of file

Comment: I am not completely certain how to tell that the exception occurs at the end. But what I tried was I but a try catch block around the while loop and in the catch part I put System.out.print(charsRead). Since the number it printed was not equal tot he total number of characters from the document I would assume that the exception does not occur at the end.

Comment: Okay, so I now also tried using Files.copy(in, path) (before I just manually added the file and read from that manually added file). With the .copy method it results in the same error and if I ignore the error then the resulting String is roughly about half the length of what it should be.

Comment: Further note it seems to work when I am reading a smaller amount of text. I was originally trying to read about 150,000 characters, but with only about 1,000 it works fine.